# create a table with a column type RECORD

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using big query and i want to create a job which populates a table with a "record" type columns.
The data will be populated by a query - so how can i write a query which returns "record" type columns.

Thanks!

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow option proposed by Pentium10 never worked for me in GBQ UI or API Explorer.
I might be missing something

Meantime, the workaround I found is as in below example

```
SELECT location.state, location.city FROM JS(
  (      // input table
  SELECT NEST(CONCAT(state, ',', city)) AS locations
  FROM (
    SELECT state, city FROM 
    (SELECT 'florida' AS state, 'miami' AS city),
    (SELECT 'california' AS state, 'la' AS city),
    (SELECT 'romania' AS state, 'transylvania' AS city)
    ) 
  ),
  locations,     // input columns
  "[    // output schema
    {'name': 'location', 'type': 'RECORD',
     'mode': 'REPEATED',
     'fields': [
       {'name': 'state', 'type': 'STRING'},
       {'name': 'city', 'type': 'STRING'}
     ]    
    }
  ]",
  "function(row, emit){    // function 
    for (var i = 0; i < row.locations.length; i++) {
      var c = [];
      x = row.locations[i].split(',');
      t = {state:x[0], city:x[1]}
      c.push(t);
      emit({location: c});  
    };
  }"
)
```

Please note:
you should set destination table with `Allow Large Results` and unchecked `Flatten Results`

Result from output table is (in JSON Mode)

```
[
  {
    "location": [
      {
        "state": "california",
        "city": "la"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "location": [
      {
        "state": "florida",
        "city": "miami"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "location": [
      {
        "state": "romania",
        "city": "transylvania"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

> Added to address some issue @AdiCohen has with his real example that
>   he showed in his recent comments:
>
> Q: my query has other columns besides the record column, but when i ran
>   the query, they return as null. how can i create a table with both of
>   the types?

```
SELECT amount, currency, location.state, location.city FROM JS( 
  ( // input table 
    SELECT NEST(CONCAT(state, ',', city)) AS locations, 
      SUM(amount) AS amount, MAX(currency) as currency 
    FROM ( 
      SELECT state, city, amount, currency, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as grp FROM 
        (SELECT 'florida' AS state, 'miami' AS city, 'coins' AS currency, 40 AS amount), 
        (SELECT 'california' AS state, 'la' AS city, 'coins' AS currency, 40 AS amount), 
        (SELECT 'romania' AS state, 'transylvania' AS city,'coins' AS currency, 40 AS amount) 
    ) GROUP BY grp
  ), 
  amount, currency, locations, // input columns 
  "[ // output schema 
    {'name': 'location', 'type': 'RECORD', 'mode': 'REPEATED', 
    'fields': [ 
      {'name': 'state', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
      {'name': 'city', 'type': 'STRING'} 
    ] }, 
    { 'name': 'amount', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, 
    { 'name': 'currency', 'type': 'STRING'} 
  ]", 
  "function(row, emit) { // function 
    for (var i = 0; i < row.locations.length; i++) { 
      var c = []; 
      x = row.locations[i].split(','); 
      t = {state:x[0], city:x[1]} 
      c.push(t); 
      emit({amount: row.amount, currency: row.currency, location: c}); 
    }; 
  }"
)
```

Output here is:

```
[
  {
    "amount": "40",
    "currency": "coins",
    "location_state": "romania",
    "location_city": "transylvania"
  },
  {
    "amount": "40",
    "currency": "coins",
    "location_state": "florida",
    "location_city": "miami"
  },
  {
    "amount": "40",
    "currency": "coins",
    "location_state": "california",
    "location_city": "la"
  }
]
```

Comment: thanks a lot! it really helped. where can i find more content about the udf function?

Comment: Hi, can you please help me? my query has other columns besides the record column, but when i ran the query, they return as null (not enough space in this comment). how can i create a table with both of the types

Comment: SELECT amount,location.state, location.city FROM JS(
  (      // input table
  SELECT NEST(CONCAT(state, ',', city)) AS locations,sum(integer(amount)) as amount
  FROM (
    SELECT state, city FROM 
    (SELECT 'florida' AS state, 'miami' AS city, 'coins' as currency, 40 as amount),
    (SELECT 'california' AS state, 'la' AS city, 'coins' as currency, 40 as amount),
    (SELECT 'romania' AS state, 'transylvania' AS city,'coins' as currency, 40 as amount)
    ) 
  ),

Comment: locations,     // input columns
  "[    // output schema
    {'name': 'location', 'type': 'RECORD',
     'mode': 'REPEATED',
     'fields': [
       {'name': 'state', 'type': 'STRING'},
       {'name': 'city', 'type': 'STRING'}
     ]    
    },
    { 'name': 'amount', 'type': 'string'}
  ]",
  "function(row, emit)
  {    // function 
    for (var i = 0; i < row.locations.length; i++) {
      var c = [];
      x = row.locations[i].split(',');
      t = {state:x[0], city:x[1]}
      c.push(t);
      emit({location: c});  
    };
  }"
)

Comment: @Adi Cohen - I will be glad to help you  - comments are not good for asking new question. I recommend you to 1. accept this answer (as looks like it works for you) and 2. post new question with all details you just provided. and I will be halppy to answer it.

Comment: Added to my answer. Hope i correctly captured your issue. Please next time ask your new/next question in new question post or (even better) make your question from the very beginning clear and full with all needed details so we dont waste too much time figuring our your case at least in terms of schemas /examples etc.

Comment: I asked  a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35040039/create-a-table-with-record-type-column. thanks!!

Comment: if you dont accept my answer above  - how i know it works for you? if i know this  - i can continue answering in that direction. if i dont - i will not as this can be just waste of my and your time?

Comment: oh.. sorry, Im not use to working with stack over flow. i accepted the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `dot` notation to reflect the output as a `RECORD` example query:

```
select 
  'florida' as country.state, 
  'SFO' as country.city;
```

In this example `country` is the record and `state|city` are fields in the record.

Comment: Please clarify - is this supposed to work with BQ UI? or API Explorer - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/insert#try-it ? Above proposed NEVER worked for me in BQ UI! Can you priovide example of working settings using API Explorer for example? Would be very helpful!

Comment: this answer is straight from paid google support from @MoshaPasumansky who provided the answer for a ticket we posted a couple of months ago

Comment: It works, but don't be fooled by the header names, try this: `select country.state from (
select 
  'florida' as country.state, 
  'SFO' as country.city
  )` To verify further, try selecting something invalid eg:  `country.xyq`  and it will respond  Field 'country.xyq' not found, so record is properly created.

Comment: the question was "create a table with a column type RECORD". so i am asking  - have you actually tried this using your answer? because, as i said - it never woked for me. Just running it w/o table creation or output to table - says nothing! At the same time  - i can miss something and that is why i am asking

Comment: I just tried and it worked, cell is a record in the new table: http://screencast.com/t/5LFSIMFJ

Comment: No. that's totally different scenario! Try to use something like in your answer

Comment: Aha, so you finally admitting that it doesnt work! :o) See my answer for workaround tottally within BigQuery w/o going outside of BQ as in answer by Google Support. to use it or not - is different story!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant well yes I wasn't aware until I dig for further info. But this is only an edge case.

Comment: this "only an edge case" is the most asked scenario I see in questions. just select * is not something that is usually of practical interest

Comment: I agree, but we need to push to get implemented properly

Comment: totally agree. this is definitelly MUST be fixed. The reason why I am "pushing" my workarounds is exactly to emphasize how rediculous it is that needs to be written to work around of relatively simple and expected things. of course another reason for workarounds is to have at least some working solution till BQ itself will be fixed

Comment: As per your knowledge what's the best way to feature this to the developers, so somebody should fix it.

Comment: Obviously BigQuery Issue Tracker - https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list - the first most available choice. Rather than this - we see some members of BigQuery Team on this site, including such prominent members as Jordan Tigani, Felipe Hoffa, Mosha Pasumansky. I hope they keep their eyes on this type of issue and escalate to respective product people so developers will have better priorities. But it is up to us to reveal such issue as critically and aggressively as possible and not qualify them as just edge cases :o) especially when they are not!

Comment: I am a bit tired to posting them, as I didn't got any real feedback on issue trackers. So I can just hope it will work. The 3 guys are doing amazing work, and they could improve this bridge somehow.