# Can an entire table (as a string) be included in a sql statement for bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I sometimes want to test certain BQ functions and sql statements in the BQ console **without** creating a test table in my dataset. For example, I can test regexp_match in the console with this:

```
Select Regexp_extract(StringToParse,r'\b(à)\b') as Extract,
 Regexp_match(StringToParse,r'\b(à)\b') as match,
FROM
(SELECT 'Voilà la séance qui est à Paris.' as StringToParse)
```

I would like to do the same using complete tables, given perhaps as a json string.

For example, if I have a test table with two records:

```
[
   {"rowNumber":1,
    "index": [1,2,3]
   },
   {"rowNumber":2,
    "index": [2,7,8,15]
   }
]
```

Can I give that table to BQ sql for testing? Something like:

```
Select max(index) as max from parse('long json string')....
```

I realize that there is no schema given, so an on-the-fly table is probably not possible.

The schema would be the following (well, with 'string' where I have an 'record' for an array of integers, probably -- that's the sort of thing I want to test):

```
[
  {
    "name":"rowNumber",
    "type":"integer"
  },
  {
    "name": "index"
    "type": "record" (oops, can't put an array of integers here...)
   },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I am answering/focusing on the question - `I sometimes want to test certain BQ functions and sql statements in the BQ console without creating a test table in my dataset`

I see few cases (it might be more but at least three below can make good start for you)

> Case #1 – Super Simple - no record type fields involved

Example:

```
SELECT a, b, c, d 
FROM 
  (SELECT 1 AS a, 'x' AS b, 'Voilà la séance qui est à Paris.' AS c, '[{"rowNumber":1,"index": [1,2,3]},{"rowNumber":2,"index": [2,7,8,15]}]' AS d),
  (SELECT 2 AS a, 'y' AS b, 'That session is in Paris.' AS c, '[{"rowNumber":3,"index": [4,5]},{"rowNumber":4,"index": [20, 23, 39]}]' AS d),
  (SELECT 3 AS a, 'z' AS b, 'Эта сессия в Париже.' AS c, '[{"rowNumber":5,"index": [6,7,8,9]},{"rowNumber":6,"index": [15, 45]}]' AS d)
```

So, now you can use this “virtual” table to experiment with your code like below

```
SELECT 
  a, b,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(c, r'(à)') AS extract,
  REGEXP_MATCH(c, r'(à)') AS match,
  JSON_EXTRACT(d, '$[1].index[0]') AS index
FROM (
  SELECT a, b, c, d 
  FROM 
    (SELECT 1 AS a, 'x' AS b, 'Voilà la séance qui est à Paris.' AS c, '[{"rowNumber":1,"index": [1,2,3]},{"rowNumber":2,"index": [2,7,8,15]}]' AS d),
    (SELECT 2 AS a, 'y' AS b, 'That session is in Paris.' AS c, '[{"rowNumber":3,"index": [4,5]},{"rowNumber":4,"index": [20, 23, 39]}]' AS d),
    (SELECT 3 AS a, 'z' AS b, 'Эта сессия в Париже.' AS c, '[{"rowNumber":5,"index": [6,7,8,9]},{"rowNumber":6,"index": [15, 45]}]' AS d)
)
```

> Case #2 – Simple with Record

If you have record with just one nested field – below makes it

```
SELECT rowNumber, NEST(index) AS index
FROM 
  (SELECT 1 AS rowNumber, 1 AS index),
  (SELECT 1 AS rowNumber, 2 AS index),
  (SELECT 1 AS rowNumber, 3 AS index),
  (SELECT 2 AS rowNumber, 2 AS index),
  (SELECT 2 AS rowNumber, 3 AS index),
  (SELECT 2 AS rowNumber, 8 AS index),
  (SELECT 2 AS rowNumber, 15 AS index)
GROUP BY rowNumber
```

You can use this as a replacement in your experimentations with “simple” record field
Btw, to confirm to yourself that this actually two rows and not 7 – run below:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS rows FROM (
  SELECT rowNumber, NEST(index) AS index
  FROM 
    (SELECT 1 AS rowNumber, 1 AS index),
    (SELECT 1 AS rowNumber, 2 AS index),
    (SELECT 1 AS rowNumber, 3 AS index),
    (SELECT 2 AS rowNumber, 2 AS index),
    (SELECT 2 AS rowNumber, 3 AS index),
    (SELECT 2 AS rowNumber, 8 AS index),
    (SELECT 2 AS rowNumber, 15 AS index)
  GROUP BY rowNumber
)
```

> Case #3 – Schema with Record of arbitrary complexity, like in example in your question

If you want to have arbitrary schema to experiment with you should first experiment a little with how to create such schemas within GBQ using JS UDF.
Check out below examples

[Create a table with Record type column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35040039/create-a-table-with-record-type-column/35043714#35043714)

[create a table with a column type RECORD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34996384/create-a-table-with-a-column-type-record/35000299#35000299)

After you master it – you can mimic any table of any complexity within GBQ and use it as sub-select (instead of real table) for experimenting with GBQ Functionality

Comment: Excellent! The UDF doc has a tester so I should be able to get up to speed on something that is above my pay grade (still digesting...) Mille mercis!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example data, the output schema you want is:

```
[
  {
    "name":"rowNumber",
    "type":"integer"
  },
  {
    "name": "index",
    "type": "integer",
    "mode": "repeated"
  },
]
```

Here's something that will work for your example, finding the `MAX` of each index.  The "SELECT NULL" in the innermost `SELECT` is unfortunate, but BigQuery complains about the use of `SPLIT` without a `FROM` clause.

```
SELECT rowNumber, MAX(index) AS max_index FROM
  (SELECT 1 AS rowNumber, INTEGER(SPLIT('1,2,3')) AS index FROM (SELECT NULL)),
  (SELECT 2 AS rowNumber, INTEGER(SPLIT('2,7,8,15')) AS index FROM (SELECT NULL))
GROUP BY rowNumber
```

If you're looking for a way to do this generally for JSON, you might investigate using the [JSON functions in the query reference.](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#jsonfunctions)

I wasn't able to get your exact example working with those functions, but depending on your JSONPath-fu / JSON structure you might be able to get something working.  This, for example, grabs the values in the first row.  Note however that output is stringified, so you get the string "[1,2,3]", but you could probably parse that into the right format with some string functions and `SPLIT`.

```
SELECT 
  JSON_EXTRACT(input, '$[0].rowNumber') as rowNumber,
  JSON_EXTRACT(input, '$[0].index') as index
FROM
  (SELECT '[
   {"rowNumber":1,
    "index": [1,2,3]
   },
   {"rowNumber":2,
    "index": [2,7,8,15]
   }
]' as input);
```

Comment: Thanks! Very useful (I did not know about json path!). To get the desired behavior, I'm going to have to cycle through the json. Or simply save it as a temporary file and then query it. And thanks for giving me the correct schema -- I would be lost without it (another learning experience about  the mode field).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that BigQuery supports a syntax like this:

```
select *
from (select 'a' as cola, 1 as col1) a,
     (select 'b', 2) b;
```

That is, you can define a table using `select` and `union all` to define a "table" in a query.

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand that syntax, and neither does BQ it seems: Error: 4.3 - 9.1: Unrecognized token SetOperation. (That's where the second SELECT starts...)