# BigQuery - remove unused column from schema

Tags: google-bigquery

I accidentally added a wrong column to my BigQuery table schema.

Instead of reloading the complete table (million of rows), I would like to know if the following is possible:

- remove bad rows (rows with values contains the wrong column) by running a "select *" query on the table with some kind of filter, and saving result to same table.
- removing the (now) unused column.

Is this functionality (or similar) supported?
Possibly the "save result to table" functionality can have a "compact schema" option.

Comment: Try one of approaches described in GCP documentation: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/manually-changing-schemas#deleting_a_column_from_a_table_schema

Answer (score 50):

The smallest time-saving way to remove a column from Big Query according to the documentation.

`ALTER TABLE [table_name] DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS [column_name]`

Comment: Yes, this is the best resolution. Deleted the whole columns in seconds.

Comment: This isn't safe, because of issues with time travel https://stackoverflow.com/a/69291989/18504339

Comment: If anyone's worried about time travel, rename the column before dropping it. Renaming the column before dropping it let's you re-create or do whatever you need after deletion. Example: `ALTER TABLE dataset.table RENAME COLUMN ColumnName TO UniqueUselessName;`

Answer (score 13):

If your table does not consist of record/repeated type fields - your simple option is:

1. Select valid columns while filtering out bad records into new temp table

   SELECT < list of original columns >
   FROM YourTable
   WHERE < filter to remove bad entries here >

   Write above to temp table - `YourTable_Temp`
2. Make a backup copy of "broken" table - `YourTable_Backup`
3. Delete `YourTable`
4. Copy `YourTable_Temp` to `YourTable`
5. Check if all looks as expected and if so - get rid of temp and backup tables

Please note: the cost of above #1 is exactly the same as action in first bullet in your question. The rest of actions (copy) are free

In case if you have repeated/record fields - you still can execute above plan, but in #1 you will need to use some [BigQuery User-Defined Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions) to have proper schema in output
You can see below for examples - of course this will require some extra dev - but if you are in critical situation - this should work for you

[Create a table with Record type column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35040039/create-a-table-with-record-type-column/35043714#35043714)
[create a table with a column type RECORD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34996384/create-a-table-with-a-column-type-record/35000299#35000299)

I hope, at some point Google BigQuery Team will add better support for cases like yours when you need to manipulate and output repeated/record data, but for now this is a best workaround I found - at least for myself

Comment: I have many repeated/record fields. That's why I use "select *" and avoid using "flatten results", to maintain the exact schema when saving to the new table.

Comment: added more to my answer related to repeated/record stuff. If you will find it useful, but will need help in implementing it - post another question with all relevant details and I will be glad to help there.

Comment: I'd add that you could even copy over all data to the temp table, and use the filtering options when copying data back to the original table. This way you can revert the operation if necessary, and not lose data from those dropped columns.

Answer (score 13):

Below is the code to do it. Lets say c is the column that you wants to delete.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE transactions.test_table AS
SELECT * EXCEPT (c) FROM  transactions.test_table;
```

Or second method and my favorite is by following below steps.

1. Write Select query with the columns you want to exclude.
2. Go to Query Settings
   [Query Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSCJ5.png)
3. In Destination setting  Set destination table for query results, enter project name, Dataset name and table name exactly same as you entered in Step 1.
4. In Destination table write preference select Overwrite table.
   [Destination table settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFDIs.png)
5. Save the Query Setting and run the query.

Comment: Not this can be used only if your table is small. When you have few TB of data you cant just randomly do that...

Comment: What it table from which you're selecting is partitioned and partition condition is required in WHERE clause?

Answer (score 0):

Save results to table is your way to go. Try on the big table with the selected columns you are interested, and you can apply a limit to make it small.

Comment: How would limit help making the schema small (not the table size)?

Comment: Limit will help to test it. You can list in the select the columns you want to retain.