# How to remove fields from big query table?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I updated schema of one production bq table and added record type of field with few repeated fields inside another record type field. Now I have to drop this column. I can't delete whole table as it already has more than 30 TB data. Is there any way to drop particular column in big query table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BigQuery - remove unused column from schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35406494/bigquery-remove-unused-column-from-schema)

Answer (score 4):

See:

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/manually-changing-schemas#deleting_a_column_from_a_table_schema

> There are two ways to manually delete a column:
>
> - Using a SQL query — Choose this option if you are more concerned about simplicity and ease of use, and you are less concerned about costs.
> - Recreating the table — Choose this option if you are more concerned about costs, and you are less concerned about simplicity and ease of use.